# Kickstart file - installer is ignoring some of the "do not install" packages from the packages section

Tags: centos, kickstart

When I use the kickstat file on CentOS 7.0, the installer seems to be ignoring some of the "do not install" packages in the list.

```
cdrom
text
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
keyboard --vckeymap=pt-latin1
lang en_US.UTF-8 --addsupport=pt_PT.UTF-8
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --ipv6=auto --activate --hostname=centos7
rootpw xxxxxx
skipx
timezone Europe/Lisbon --isUtc --nontp
firstboot --disabled
services --enabled sshd
firewall --enabled --ssh --http
clearpart --all --initlabel
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
autopart --type=lvm
reboot --eject

%packages --nobase --excludedocs
@core
-acl
-authconfig
-dracut*
-kexec-tools
-linux-firmware
-newt*
-plymouth-scripts
%end
```

I see no obvious errors on the install, but some of the packages are there when I boot the system (some aren't). I can remove them using:

```
yum remove acl authconfig dracut* linux-firmware newt* plymouth-scripts
```

So they aren't system protected packages. Is there a way to avoid installing them, or do I need to remove them after install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kickstart file seems to be fine. The only package that should be logic to have during installation and removed after is `authconfig`. This guy [seems to be required](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html) during installation to configure your authentication scheme on this kind of deploy

This is not the ideal solution, but how about if you create a [post install block](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html#sect-kickstart-postinstall) and add your `yum remove` line. These packages will be removed right after the installation, and before the first reboot into the installed system:

```
%post
yum remove -y acl authconfig dracut* linux-firmware newt* plymouth-scripts
%end
```

Comment: `yum` normally prompts for confirmation before performing operations, so I'd recommend `yum remove -y acl authconfig dracut* linux-firmware newt* plymouth-scripts`. Otherwise the post section is liable to get blocked. Best case scenario the prompt gets killed eventually (which would mean the packages don't get removed). Worst case the installation never finishes.

Comment: Good catch. Edited my answer to reflect your improvement :)